# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "simple_form"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, bundler, client-side-validation

I'm having hard time trying to install the gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form'. My Gemfile looks like

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.0.0'
gem 'simple_form', '2.1.0'

gem 'client_side_validations', '3.2.5'
gem "client_side_validations-simple_form", '2.0.1'
gem 'client_side_validations-turbolinks', '1.0.0'
```

When I run Bundle install I get

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "simple_form":
  In Gemfile:
    client_side_validations-simple_form (= 2.0.1) ruby depends on
      simple_form (~> 2.0.3) ruby

    simple_form (2.1.0)
```

Am I missing something here?  Does anyone have expirienced the same issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client-side-validations gem depends on simple_form 2.0.3, while you use 2.1.0. So basically your version of simple form is too new (or your version of client_side_validations-simple_form too old).

If the version of client_side_validations-simple_form you use is the most recent, then use an older version of simple_form until an updated version of client_side_validations-simple_form comes along that works with a more recent version of simple_form.

For now:

```
gem 'simple_form', '2.0.3'
```